# Are there grammars for subset of English?

Tags: english, grammar, parsing

I'm looking for grammar for relatively simple subset of English, tokens in which contain only letters, digits and comma. No quotes, colons, dashes and so on. Is there such thing? If no, is there other (free) grammars for subsets of English?

Comment: Probably, but the deal is that if you define the subset, you write the grammar. Because the grammar **is** the definition of the subset.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is a simple subset of English. I don't want to get into terminological niceties, but even if you consider punctuation a part of grammar, leaving it out takes away something like 3 % of its complexity.

Comment: A grammar (at least as linguists understand it) does not deal with letters, digits or commas. It deals with morphemes, words, and the arrangement of words (syntax). In computer science you can have grammars of symbols, but "grammar" in this sense has little in common with the grammar of natural languages, and the domain of the grammar will not have more than a superficial resemblance to English

Comment: I'd say it's safe to assume that there is no 100% complete grammar of English, so therefore we *only* have grammars for subsets of English.

Comment: It's true what @ColinFine says, but *symbol* has multiple meanings. What he says is mostly based on a symbol being a *glyph*. But if you go back to the root of what *symbol* means, something with *represents* something else, then languages are based on symbols because words are arbitrary things which represent things, concepts, categories, etc. This is why computers in general and neural networks specifically did not handle language as easily as advanced mathematics. Because handling symbols is very different from handing numbers. One of the very early AI systems was named *Symbolics* in fact.

Comment: @hippietrail: that's true, but it takes it even further from the question than I did, because _symbols_ in that sense have almost nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: @ColinFine: Well I would disagree from my perspective as a language enthusiast, programming enthusiast, and with some experience playing with grammars and parsers of both kinds. But I probably lack the eloquence to explain it.

Comment: @hippietrail: Maybe you're right. I was concerned to point out to DSblizzard that thinking in terms of letters and punctuations marks was utterly wrong for considering anything resembling the grammar of English

Comment: Well yes that part is totally true. OP seems to tackling or asking about something they're not ready for or don't understand yet.